# How to call a class from a javascript string

Tags: javascript, node.js, class

I am making a nodejs server. I have made a system where I need to dynamically load different classes. The name of the classes are in string. It looks like this:

```
var classname = "foo"; // this is the name of the class I want to call.

var bar = new classname //classname needs to be foo in this example.
```

I already tried `window[classname]` but this wont work because this is nodejs so there is no window to work with.

Thank you for reading :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The better approach is to make use of a JSON object. To achieve that , you can always have a `key:value` JSON object where the key corresponds to your variable. See the example below. The variable `classname` is actually a `key` of the JSON object `obj` then you can easily reference that to simulate as if you are creating a new class:

```
var obj = {
   classname : 'foo'
};

var bar = new obj['classname'];
```

Comment: why  `classname` wrap with string in last line?

Comment: because that is not a `variable` and when you are accessing using square brackets without variable name then you need quotes else you can also do `new obj.classname;`

Comment: can I use this with es6 classes too?

Comment: Yes you can use it

Comment: but that is key and it is constant what if use `new obj[classname]`

Comment: like you can use `new obj[variableHere]`  where `variableHere` will have value `classname` then `new obj[variableHere]` will be `new foo`

Comment: What is the difference?

Comment: I was just giving you an example. Where you can set the value of `variableHere` dynamically with the `key` name for whose `value` you want to create class

Comment: @AKA I used your code but now I get `TypeError: obj.classname is not a constructor`

Answer (score 2):

`eval("new " + classname)` but "beware, [eval is evil](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/197769/when-is-javascripts-eval-not-evil)", etc.

Comment: Wow thank you for the link that was very useful. In my case I cant use eval because the classname will come from the url so its not very save.